# Why does one font work in IE but the other doesn't

Tags: html, css, font-face, truetype

HTML

```
<span style="font-family: 'blackjackregular'; font-size: 18pt;">My</span>
<span style="font-family: 'trajanpro'; font-size: 14pt;">WEST</span>
```

Font css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'trajanpro';
    src: url('trajanpro-regular.eot');
    src: url('trajanpro-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('trajanpro-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('trajanpro-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('trajanpro-regular.svg#trajanpro_regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'blackjackregular';
    src: url('blackjar-webfont.eot');
    src: url('blackjar-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('blackjar-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('blackjar-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('blackjar-webfont.svg#blackjackregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

IE Shows:

[image]

FF and Chrome Shows:

[image]

As you can see the MY is correct in both IE and other browsers but why isn't WEST not changing font in IE?

Comment: Which version of IE ?

Comment: The question says that of two fonts, one works and the other doesn’t, without giving any real information about the two fonts, just the names that you have assigned to them in CSS.

Comment: Agree but in the description I gave the code and also explained which is working and which isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trajan Pro is Adobe's proprietary font and might not have a license for embedding it as a web font. Embedding it with `@font-face` probably violates the EULA. To use it you'll need to use a service like Typekit. Please see details here: https://typekit.com/fonts/trajan-pro-3

EDIT:

After some more digging here's an interesting [link](http://blog.themeforest.net/general/font-licensing-for-the-web/), stating that IE implements a flag in EOT files restricting use of fonts. Other browsers do not implement this feature, or plan to, hence difference in behavior.

Comment: Are you saying chrome ignores the license, but IE doesn't?

Comment: I had a feeling because when trying to convert in one website it didn't allow me but another website did.

Comment: It maybe violates some law, but the thing is : why it's working in other browser and not IE ?

Comment: Exactly my question. Maybe IE8 had a better license check?

Comment: @enguerranws Please see here http://blog.themeforest.net/general/font-licensing-for-the-web/    Quote: "Microsoft uses the .eot font format (Embedded OpenType) as a solution to this problem. EOT is supposed to respect the flags in the font files for embedding and can be limited to specific domains. Non-IE browsers however, have not adopted this technology and don’t plan to. "

Comment: Ohhh... Well I do have the license for the font because it was purchased but not for web font it seems. Thanks for the info. Upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be the EOT flags on the font that IE applies, when the other browser don't, as Jacek Glen said.

**You should check for free equivalent to Trajan, like Cinzel** :http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cinzel

I'm not sure, but try that :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'trajanpro';

src: url('trajanpro-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('trajanpro-regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('trajanpro-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('trajanpro-regular.svg#trajanpro_regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'blackjackregular';

src: url('blackjar-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('blackjar-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('blackjar-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('blackjar-webfont.svg#blackjackregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

I just removed the first "src" property, that shoudn't be specified twice. No idea why that would work for "My" and not for "west"...

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that didn't solve the issue. I did upvote for the try :)

Comment: You should check for free equivalent to Trajan, like Cinzel :http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cinzel

Comment: Thank you. It's not quiet the same :/

Comment: Look for another equivalent then, but I don't think you will be able to make Trajan work in IE8 (because of the legal stuff :) )

Comment: I will have to do that unfortunately.